# how to get WebDriver for my Listener class when using "public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webdriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();" method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I keep getting NullPointerException for my Listener's WebDriver. is this because I used ThreadLocal on my WebDriver in base class? if so how do I get the test case's driver for my listener's onTestSuccess method?

This is my Listener Class:

```
@Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        extentTest.get().log(Status.PASS,"Test Passed");
        WebDriver driver = null;
        Object testObject = result.getInstance();
        Class clazz = result.getTestClass().getRealClass();
        try {
            driver = (WebDriver)clazz.getField("webdriver").get(testObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            extentTest.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenShotPath(result.getMethod().getMethodName(), driver), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

BaseClass:

```
public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webdriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();


@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    Reporter.log("@@@@@ Setup @@@@@",true);
    ExtentReports extent = ExtentReport.extentReportGenerator();
}


@BeforeMethod
public void startBrowser() {
    WebDriverFactory webDriverFactory = new WebDriverFactory();
    webDriverFactory.setDriver();
    webdriver.set(webDriverFactory.getDriver());
    webdriver.get().get(baseURL);
```

TestCase Class:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "jsonData", dataProviderClass = TestData.class)
public void  testAggregator(String jSon) throws ParseException {
    extent.createTest("Test The Welcome Page");
    welcomePageImpl = new WelcomePageImpl(webdriver.get());
    welcomePageImpl.getAggregatorRequest(webdriver.get(),jSon);
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.java.com.shoppingCart.testCases.BaseClass.getScreenShotPath(BaseClass.java:71)
    at main.java.com.shoppingCart.utilities.Listeners.onTestSuccess(Listeners.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:70)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:219)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:651)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It will help if you post the exception stack trace upto 4-5 levels.

Comment: did I add the exception correctly?

Comment: ahh I think I got the fix. I had to set the WebDriver to public lol

Comment: and get the class from BaseClass.class; and not the test class

Comment: ahh never mind. its only working when I'm not using ThreadLocal webdriver

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your test code.

`onSuccess` is NOT guaranteed by TestNG to run in the same thread as your test method.

To fix this, please refactor your listener to use `beforeInvocation` and `afterInvocation` via the TestNG listener interface `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` because that is guaranteed to run on the same thread (as far as I can remember).

Comment: Yup I tried it and learned that its creating test for every method. I want something where it can get the single @ Test method and create screenshots when it fails or pass under the @ test method title in the reporter.

Comment: found the issue.